# Does FFMpeg support encoding a group of raw frames with out-of-band timestamps into a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Suppose I have a group of raw frames captured from a camera and a csv file listing the exact time the frame are captured. Notice the frames are not captured at a constant rate.

Is that possible to encode such raw frames into a video with FFMpeg and somehow make FFMpeg to attach timestamp to each frame based on the time information stored in the csv?

I found a 2012 post at https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-December/011907.html, which seems to suggest the answer then was negative. Not sure whether anything has changed since.

Comment: First three steps in the answer [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/19723/1871) are relevant. Alternatively, you can use the slideshow method [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer) where duration is denominated in fractional seconds.

Comment: @Mulvya You may provide that as an actual answer, perhaps adding / citing the most relevant parts here.

Comment: @slhck sure, but let the OP verify it works for them.

Comment: @Mulvya, thanks for the pointers. Both of them seems to be able to solve my problem.